# ASP.Net Meta Tags: Programmatically populate Title, Keywords and Description in Page Head Section from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, url-rewriting, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to create search option in my ASP.net application to check Doctor details based on Location. If I try the below code, only home page is showing. `http://example.com/Metatag/Home.aspx`. I want the URL to be changed as per location. Example expected URL:`http://example.com/Metatag/chennai/doctors/saidapet`

I'm new to this technology.

Page Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string page = Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];
     string location = Request.Url.Segments[Request.Url.Segments.Length - 1];
     DataTable dtMeta = this.GetData(page,location);

     //Add Page Title
     this.Page.Title = dtMeta.Rows[0]["Title"].ToString();

     //Add Keywords Meta Tag
     HtmlMeta keywords = new HtmlMeta();
     keywords.HttpEquiv = "keywords";
     keywords.Name = "keywords";
     keywords.Content = dtMeta.Rows[0]["Keywords"].ToString();
     this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(keywords);

     //Add Description Meta Tag
     HtmlMeta description = new HtmlMeta();
     description.HttpEquiv = "description";
     description.Name = "description";
     description.Content = dtMeta.Rows[0]["Description"].ToString();
     this.Page.Header.Controls.Add(description);
 }
```

GetData Table

```
private DataTable GetData(string page,string location)
{
    string query = "SELECT Title, Description, Keywords FROM MetaTags WHERE LOWER(Page,Location) = LOWER(@Page,@Location)";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Page", page);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", location);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                return dt;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Database:

[image: Get url with location]

Am trying [this code](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-Meta-Tags-Programmatically-populate-Title-Keywords-and-Description-in-Page-Head-Section-from-database.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Use `Page.MetaKeywords` like [this link](http://www.asprobot.com/ASP.NET/ASPNET-Title-Tag-and-Meta-Tags)

```
Page.Title = "Your Page Title";
Page.MetaDescription = "Your Page Description";
Page.MetaKeywords = "Your Page Keywords";
```

And for URL rewriting use [this tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Easy-Steps-to-URL-2f792901/view/SourceCode#content)